# bootstrap горизонтальное расположение элементов меню с переходом в выпадающий список

Tags: php, css, bootstrap

У меня есть горизонтальная менюшка фиксированной ширины, куда пользователь может добавлять пункты и называть их по своему усмотрению, таким образом каждое название пункта будет иметь разную ширину зависящую от названия и выводиться в виде ссылки. Я не понимаю как узнать в какой момент нужно перестать располагать элементы горизонтально, если они перестают умещаться, и начать заворачивать их в выпадающий список с помощью php и css.

Comment: тут тебе JS только в помощь. Отслеживайте изменения высоты родительского элемента, как только высота изменилась, меняйте на выпадающий список.

Comment: не силен в js, но принцип я понял! Спасибо :)